# How to sort a list alphabetically?

Tags: r, list, sorting

It is necessary to create a list of random letters of the alphabet. And then sort it alphabetically. To create such a list, I use the following code:

```
# Creating a random vector of letters
random_text_data = sample(letters, 10)
random_text_data

# Convert to list
list_text_data = as.list(random_text_data)
list_text_data
```

In the console I get the following:

```
> random_text_data
 [1] "h" "m" "q" "b" "z" "i" "y" "f" "d" "e"
> # Convert to list
> list_text_data = as.list(random_text_data)
> list_text_data
[[1]]
[1] "h"

[[2]]
[1] "m"

[[3]]
[1] "q"

[[4]]
[1] "b"

[[5]]
[1] "z"

[[6]]
[1] "i"

[[7]]
[1] "y"

[[8]]
[1] "f"

[[9]]
[1] "d"

[[10]]
[1] "e"
```

Now I need to sort it alphabetically. I have tried the following:

```
# Sort list alphabetically
sort_data = sort(list_text_data)
```

But get error:

```
> sort_data = sort(list_text_data)
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
'x' must be elementary
```

How should you sort?

Comment: Every list item has 1 character? Why not unlist sort then convert back to list again?

Comment: `as.list(sort(unlist(list_text_data)))`

Comment: @zx8754, Yes, it would be logical, but the task is set like this: "Create a list of Latin letters. Sort list in alphabetical order"

Comment: I am assuming they might have meant a vector, and not the list object.

Comment: @zx8754, I will probably use this approach, I hope that they will count. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method that do not need to `unlist()`. After making the list with random letters, assign names to the list with the content of the list. Then order the names within the list.

### Input

```
random_text_data = sample(letters, 10)

[1] "c" "v" "m" "g" "h" "l" "d" "i" "u" "y"
```

### Original solution

```
list_text_data = as.list(random_text_data)

list_text_data <- setNames(list_text_data, list_text_data)

list_text_data[order(names(list_text_data))]

$c
[1] "c"

$d
[1] "d"

$g
[1] "g"

$h
[1] "h"

$i
[1] "i"

$l
[1] "l"

$m
[1] "m"

$u
[1] "u"

$v
[1] "v"

$y
[1] "y"
```

### Updated solution

Inspired by @zx8754's answer, you don't actually need to change names of the list, you can use `setNames` within `order`, then the output will be an unnamed list.

```
list_text_data[order(names(setNames(list_text_data, list_text_data)))]

[[1]]
[1] "c"

[[2]]
[1] "d"

[[3]]
[1] "g"

[[4]]
[1] "h"

[[5]]
[1] "i"

[[6]]
[1] "l"

[[7]]
[1] "m"

[[8]]
[1] "u"

[[9]]
[1] "v"

[[10]]
[1] "y"
```

Comment: yes, it works) I will start your answer after the timer ends

Answer (score 3):

Convert character to integer, then order:

```
# reproducible example data
set.seed(1); random_text_data = sample(letters, 3)
list_text_data = as.list(random_text_data)
# [[1]]
# [1] "y"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "d"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "g"


# sort
list_text_data[ order(sapply(list_text_data, utf8ToInt)) ]
# [[1]]
# [1] "d"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "g"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "y"
```

Answer (score 1):

We may have to flatten the list first before sorting the elements. We can try the `sort` + `unlist` like below

```
relist(sort(unlist(list_text_data)), list_text_data)
```